# Creating a Live USB with Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator that has persistent storage mounted on boot?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, live-usb, usb-creator

A friend of mine is constantly switching between different laptops that he's working on and he would like to have a Live USB with persistent storage (For Firefox bookmarks, email, etc.) that he can save to the live USB drive so that it all transfers as he's moving between machines.

Is there a way to do this with Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator so that USB drive has a partition that is mounted to a user home directory on startup?

Comment: SDC makes a read only USB stick, you can't add persistence. Mkusb makes a nice persistent drive or else you can unplug your internal drive and do a Full install to a USB as you would to internal drive. It is more stable and upgradeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can only create live (live-only) systems with the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator (in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions). The reason is that it is a cloning tool, that clones the content from the iso file with the read-only file system iso 9660.
- But there are several tools that can create persistent live systems. I would recommend [**`mkusb`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), which creates a partition with the label `casper-rw` for persistence. This means that the whole USB drive will be used.

  There are several tools that create persistent live systems with a FAT32 file system, where the content from the iso file is extracted, and a file with the name `casper-rw`. Because of the FAT32 file system, the size of that file is limited to 4 GiB.
- Links

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

  [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)